# Geting Failed to open TCP connection to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443 (execution expired)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive this error:
`Failed to open TCP connection to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443 (execution expired)`

while running some feature specs

I have this in my Gemfile:

```
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
```

Locally I have chromiuum installed and it is on my path.

any hint is welcome, thx

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error before. What helped me resolve it was to make sure Google Chrome and Chromedriver have matching versions (and reinstalling them if necessary).

For context: I was attempting to change my version of Google Chrome *from* `114.0.5735.198` to `114.0.5735.90`, I purged Google Chrome and then reinstalled it from scratch. `chromedriver -v` was still showing the desired version (`114.0.5735.90`) but maybe something happened during the purge because this was when I started seeing the error

> Failed to open TCP connection to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443 (execution expired)

when running my rspec tests. Reinstalling chromedriver resolved the issue.